# How do I fix column count in adb shell?

Tags: android, shell, terminal, adb

When bash (or other shell) fails to guess the correct column count on your terminal, it gets inconvenient to edit long lines.

For usual Linux systems, there is script [termsize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-termsize/0.1) that automatically fixes the terminal size. But typical Android does not have Python, so `termsize` can't work.

How do I fix the terminal width in `adb shell`?

Answer (score 1):

This snippet can assist you for setting up column count:

```
echo "\033[18t"; { sleep 1; echo -n "COLUMNS="; } &  grep -m 1 -o '[0-9]*t' | { sleep 2; grep -m 1 -o '[0-9]*'; }
```

Usage:

1. Open `adb shell`;
2. Insert the snippet into command line;
3. Execute it (press <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and immediately press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again.
4. Wait for 2 seconds: it should print `COLUMNS=` after 1 second and the columns count after another 1 second;
5. Copy `COLUMNS=NNN` into console and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> yet again.

Example session:

```
$ adb shell
9]*t' | { sleep 2; grep -m 1 -o '[0-9]*'; }                                   <

[1] 17212
^[[8;38;149t
COLUMNS=149

[1] + Done                 { sleep 1 ; echo -n "COLUMNS=" ; } 
shell@hwH60:/ $ COLUMNS=149
shell@hwH60:/ $
```